# PHP-Modifing Pagination for Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, html, pagination

Hi i am a new programmer.

i have a simple **pagination** which **works fine**, 
i have **sorting** options for sorting  my recordset result by id, title etc which is also **working fine**, the codes are below.

now i want to **combine both** and have a functionality that pagination should work on both conditions.

that is when recordset result is displayed by default pagination should work as before.
and  when recordset result is sorted by options pagination should work on sorted result too.

i got something figured out, the codes are below, but i cant get it to work.

my code for recordset and basic pagination-sorting are:

```
<?php 
$table='mytable';
$pagename = "is-test.php";
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
$numrows = $row[0];
$rowsperpage = 5;
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
$currentpage = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
} else {
$currentpage = 1;
}
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
$currentpage = $totalpages;
}
if ($currentpage < 1) {
$currentpage = 1;
}
$orderBy = array('id', 'title',);
$order = '';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['orderBy']);
}else{
$order='id';
}
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $order ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$startrow = ($currentpage-1) * $rowsperpage
```

my codes for sorting options:

```
         Sort by
        <a href="?orderBy=id">id:</a>        

        <a href="?orderBy=title">title:</a>
```

my codes for pagination are:

```
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
}

if($currentpage<$totalpages){
for ($x = ($currentpage - 3); $x < (($currentpage + 3) + 1); $x++) {
if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
if ($x == $currentpage) {
echo " <li id='pcurrent'><a href='$pagename?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
} else {
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?page=$x'>$x</a></li> ";
}}}  
}

if ($currentpage > 1){
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?page=$prevpage'>&laquo;&laquo;Prev</a></li> ";
}
```

upto now everytthing is working except pagination only paginate defaut recordset resunt not sorted recordset result for that i have to change url parameter for pagination to work on sorting result, 
so i have changed my pagination links as

```
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
}

if($currentpage<$totalpages){
for ($x = ($currentpage - 3); $x < (($currentpage + 3) + 1); $x++) {
if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
if ($x == $currentpage) {
echo " <li id='pcurrent'><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
} else {
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?orderBy=$order,page=$x'>$x</a></li> ";
}}}  
}

if ($currentpage > 1){
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?page=$prevpage'>&laquo;&laquo;Prev</a></li> ";
}
```

i.e added **orderBy=$order** in links for pagination, but pagination is not working now,
not on default recordset result and not on sorted recordset result.

please see what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the whole code but you have at least one error in your query string. Each GET-parameter should be separated by "&" instead of "," what you did. Changing your code from

```
'?orderBy=$order,page=$nextpage'
```

to

```
'?orderBy=$order&page=$nextpage'
```

should fix this error at least.

You should put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your code to see notices from php (which would have helped you a lot). If it's still not working afterwards you should debug your GET params with

```
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

Comment: also looking at above what are ways to prevent sql injections i have used mysql_real_escape_string for _GET is that make it injection proof

Comment: using mysql_real_escape_string to escape $order is definitely a good idea. Using it on $page is optional since you're casting it to an integer anyway

Comment: hi can you also tell me how to further sort id and title in ASC and DESC the same way in query.

Comment: i figured it out, just implemented &sort in ASC part of mysql query and modifying url with sortby=&sort got it there